# WPF Path Некорректное отображение

Tags: c#, wpf

Я создаю стиль кнопки, которая должна содержать прямую линию:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Path x:Name="Mark" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M0,0 L10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#D2D2D2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C8C8C8"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Но вместо черты шириной в 1px я всегда получаю черту шириной 2px:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал использовать и не использовать `UseLayoutRounding="True"`, `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`, `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"`, `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` но ничего из этого не влияет на отображение в данном случае - черта всегда 2px. Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Масштабироавние монитора какое установлено? Версия дотнета какая используется? Судя по всему у вас 4к монитор с масштабом 200% или более. 1px - это логический пиксель, а не физический в данном случае. Чтобы получить физический, толщину 1px надо поделить на масштаб текущего монитора, то есть для 200% будет 1/2=0,5px. Ну и плюс ко всему само приложение должно быть DPI-Aware, если дотнет новый, оно по умолчанию работает, если Framework 4.x, то не факт.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5, масштаб 125%, разрешение 1920x1080, Windows 10

Comment: Ну значит ваше приложение ничего не знает о масштабе. Берите .NET 6 или новее, и там всё будет из коробки. А если не хочется, то изучайте как включить DPI Awareness руками. То есть когда вы указываете 1px, приложение вам 1 и рисует и ничего не знает о масштабе 125%, а растягивает его в нужный масштаб сама винда, вот и получается мыльная каша. Хотите убедиться, поставьте 100% и пиксель сам станет пикселем, приложение только перезапустить надо будет.

Comment: Я попробовал определить системное значение DPI для окна и значение которое видит WPF: 
`PresentationSource presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(window);
                double wpfDpi = 96.0 * presentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
                double currentDpi = GetDpiForWindow(hWnd);`. Они совпадают (120). Получается приложение знает о масштабе.

Comment: При этом наклонные линии отображаются чётко (выглядят тонкими), а прямые (вертикальные или горизонтальные) - относительно широкие.

Comment: Так же для проверки я попробовал установить системный масштаб 100%, но ситуация не изменилась - линии по 2px

Comment: @aepot Есть идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение заключается в следующей комбинации значений: `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"`, `UseLayoutRounding="False"`, `SnapsToDevicePixels="False"`.